# Need CSS tweak for "close" button from jQueryTools.org

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, jquery-tools

(This is not a backlink by any means! It's just where I have the file.) It would help if you have firebug to take a look since the css is all over the place:

http://www.myproduction-1.info/jquery_tools_org_overlay/blue.html

I just need to figure out the CSS to make the close button a link. I believe the following are the relevant parts.

JavaScript:

```
$("#prompt form").submit(function(e) {

    // close the overlay
    triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();

});
```

CSS:

```
#prompt.modal {
background-image: url("_img/VPN-Overlay-R2_698x535.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #FBFFFF;
display: none;
left: 50%!important;
position: fixed;
top: 50%!important;
z-index: 9999;
height: 535px;
opacity: 0.8;
margin: -267px 0 0 -377px;
padding-left: 287px;
padding-top: 385px;
}
```

Comment: Always include the relevant markup and such **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question If it's long, create an http://http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it with code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to make a lightbox is not to overlay it as a div and have the background image be a screenshot of a lightbox.

Try using this API instead: http://fancybox.net

Comment: I need something where I can put the 2 radio buttons on top of the background image.

Comment: I think the fancybox iframe should do it, no? it just doesn't have a background image, which I can add...

Comment: yep you could pretty much anything in there